# iOS custom view consuming touch events

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am implementing a custom view to handle editing of a image(very specific purpose) and am stuck in handling of touch events

According to my logic after overriding `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` and implementing them so if the touch hits the target (part of the view) I am doing stuff with the event and ***_not_*** calling `[super touchesXXX]` the event shouldn't be passed to its parent `UIResponders`

However, my view lays on `UIPageViewController` and the touch events are working great, but for some reason the `UIPageViewController` also at all times receives the events and takes over with swiping gesture which makes me unable to perform actions that require touchesMoved, because everytime the touch moves horizontally `UIPageViewController` recognizes it as swipe

so basically my code is as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if([self withinBounds:touches]) {
        //do own stuff
    } else {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

and I've done debug printing and everything works perfectly until I do a horizontal move, it never calls super's touchesBegan or touchesMoved or anything, but yet the gesture gets activated

I've also tried overriding the gesture by setting custom `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate which on shouldReceiveTouch method returns NO always, but still the swipe gesture keeps on going

Also if it matters, my target platform is iOS 8.1 and I am running the app on the simulator

Comment: What about a `resignFirstResponder`or something like that? iOS applications respectively, actively use the chain-of-responsibility pattern for handling events, and touch events.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the UIPageViewController gesture recognizers for the duration of any touch events you want to track.

Your custom view will keep a reference to the UIPageViewController gesture recognizers.  It then simply disables the gestures in `-touchesBegan:` and re-enables the gestures in `-touchesCancelled:` and `-touchesEnded:`.

E.g.:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray* overriddenGestures;
@end

@implementation MyView
- (void)setGesturesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* gr in _overriddenGestures)
    {
        gr.enabled = enabled;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"BEGIN: %@", event);
    [self setGesturesEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"CANCEL: %@", event);
    [self setGesturesEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"END: %@", event);
    [self setGesturesEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"MOVE: %@", event);
}
@end
```

You can then assign `UIPageViewController.gestureRecognizers` to your view's `overriddenGestures` property.

Alternatively, if you want to restrict the UIPageViewController's gestures to a specific region of the screen, place an empty UIView in the desired region of the screen and attach the UIPageViewController's gestures to that view.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to achieve this with a scrollview or a class that inherits from it. The two gestures are identical and the scrollview has clearly the first shot being higher in the view hierarchy.

Either dont use a pageviewcontroller or create a more complex touch logic.

For instance you could check for a long press on the image you want to edit. If a long press happens then disable the userinteraction for the scrollview, handle the move for your image and enable the interaction afterwards.

Comment: the logic is pretty simple, but the question is, how do I disable the userinteraction for scroll view? I mean, if I return NO on shouldReceiveTouch of the delegate of the scroll view, it still receives events and does its things.

Comment: An UIScrollView inherits from UIView. So, yes you can set him to make him unresponsive during runtime.